# How can I do OAuth request by open new window, instead of redirect user from current page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, popup

I have done OAuth authentication with Twitter and Facebook. Currently, with each of these site, my server redirect user to a specified URL (for example, http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize with Twitter), then receive authentication parameters by callback url.

But by that way, the users get redirected out of my page (to Facebook or Twitter), and only returns after input correct username & password. It's like the way http://techcrunch.com do it when a user try to tweet a post.

I remember that in some site, I have seen that we can connect not by redirect user out, but open a popup window for user to input credentials instead. After authentication is completde, the pop-up closed, the main page refresh with new content.

This could be a very simple task with javascript, but I still can't figure it out. I can open authentication URL in a pop-up window, but how to get the result & update the main page?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Assuming you're opening authentication url in a pop-up using `window.open()`, you can access parent window by using:

```
window.opener
```

and to **reload** parent window (from a pop-up) use:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

This code should be served on url that you've set up as success callback url of oauth authorization.

In general, the flow should be:

- open a pop-up with an authorization page (on twitter.com for example)
- after successfull authorization twitter redirects user to url given by you (it gets opened in the very same pop-up)
- the opener window gets reloaded (via `window.opener.location.reload()`)
- close the pop-up itself (using javascript is you want)

Comment: you mean I put javascript in the popup window to do this?

Comment: Yep, in the pop-up, on a page that is a success callback of oauth authorization. So the flow is: you open a pop-up with an authorization page (on twitter.com for example), after successfull authorization twitter redirects user to url given by you (it gets opened in the very same pop-up), on that callback page you put a javascript from my answer, the *opener* window gets reloaded and you can simply close the pop-up using javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a follow up ques:
Does it matter from the Twitter implementation point of view whether we have opened the authorization page in the the new window or in the same window. What I mean is, does twitter implementation will change if they have to redirect me to the new window (that I have opened for authorization page) vs they have to redirect me to the same window (in case i have not opened the new window for authorization page)

Comment: Hi @ankur rawat, I don't think Twitter implementation will change - they always redirect back the call to the caller page, regardless it's the main window or a pop up (I'm assuming they haven't changed the implementation details, it's 10 years since I asked this question).

Comment: Just FYI, the answer post isn't the right place to ask further question. Understanding you might not have the right to comment yet - I'd suggest next time you open a new question to ask - you can refer to the referred question as an URL in your new question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).