# Communicating between a page and a popup oauth page

Tags: php, jquery, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an application that has a button which opens a blank page for linkedin oauthentication.

My question is, when the user completes authentication and processing for linkedin, how do I tell the original page that this process is complete?

I was thinking about creating an ajax method that tells the database that the user is in oauth and when they are complete we tell the same database that the process is over and the original page will find out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See: [How can I do OAuth request by open new window, instead of redirect user from current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606071/how-can-i-do-oauth-request-by-open-new-window-instead-of-redirect-user-from-cur)

The trick is the `window.opener` property, available from the popup. Using that you could do something simple like a reload `window.opener.location.reload()` or possibly something more complicated using `postMessage` (in either case the code would live in the page that OAuth redirects to on completion).