# Redirect OAuth screen to a new window

Tags: python, django, oauth

I am building a django application which uses OAuth to get Google drive access. However when I run the flow to get the credentials, the OAuth screen opens in another tab which diverts the user to another window. How do I make the OAuth appear in a popup window and close when authentication is done ?

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
    flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
    if flags:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
    else: 
        credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
```

I believe the tools.run_flow is the method that calls the OAuth screen in another tab.

Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606071/how-can-i-do-oauth-request-by-open-new-window-instead-of-redirect-user-from-cur