# Spotify OAUTH redirect to parent page after closing popup

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, spotify

So I create a popup window for `OAuth` authorization on Spotify and when user accepts, it redirects to a callback url. But this happens in the popup and not the parent page. The  `callback URL` has a code needed by an access token and I was wondering how i could pass that code to the parent page and reload the `callback`url in the parent page.

User clicks `login`

```
 <a href=# onclick="pop()" class="nav-link">Login</a>
     
<script>
    function pop() {window.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/login/','pop',"height=590,width=450,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=auto,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no");}
</script>
```

The `callback url` in the popup after logging in is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/callback/?code=xxxxxxx`, how do I make this load in the parent page?

I tried this JS in the callback route but did not work;

```
 <script>
function redirectToCallback(){
window.opener.location.reload();
    }
redirectToCallback();
</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607058/14517835 used this link, but the answer is what I am trying to implement but to no avail.